# Extracting relations with OSMnx

Tags: tags, relationship, openstreetmap, osmnx

I am using osmnx package https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html to extract data from OSM. I want to obtain the cyclist node network in Flanders. After some info about tagging, I found the most useful tag could be "network:type"; but when I used it, I only obtain nodes as element type.

Maybe my approach to extract relations is inadequate?.

```
place= "Leuven, Flanders, Belgium"
tags = {"network:type":"node_network"}
Leuven_test = ox.geometries_from_place(place,tags,which_result=None)
```

```
Leuven_test.head()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jANa2.jpg)

```
Leuven_test.plot()
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T5TC.jpg)

I think the issue is the difference between Nominatim API and Overpass API. I made a query in Over pass turbo and suceed getting the data. But I want to do it on Phyton, as I need the complete network.

Please, any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Are you trying to get the cycling network, or just some geometries of it?

Comment: I want to get the Node cycling network (https://www.fietsroute.org/Cycle-Networks.html). Mainly, I want all the ways connecting the nodes as I want to quantify the km of bike infraestructure. @gboeing.